# how to make background fit content and not full width of container in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a card using bootstrap. i'm adding a bg color to a div inside the card body however, the background is extending across all the width of the container. Here's a pic of the card im working on:

[image: the card im working on]

**How** can i make the background color of the div that contains the picture and the name of the user to only fit to the content and not to 100% width of the card?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">

     <h5 class="card-title text-center">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>

     <div class="text-center userbg rounded-pill">
      <a href=""><img class="img-fluid rounded-circle myImg" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gj07ovBA5rvPW7w90kJll5j3_oqFbc1hpADM4F91w"> 
     <span>User</span>
       </a>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myImg {
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;
}

.userbg {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
```

Comment: The main difficulty here is because the image is larger than you are displaying it. Is it possible to use a smaller image or do you need to keep the code like it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of a `<div>` is to be a block-level element, which means that it will always take 100% of the available width unless this behavior is overridden.  There are a couple of different approaches you could take to resolve this, either change the nature of your `<div>` wrapper, or eliminate that entirely and apply the changes to your anchor tag.

Below is an example of what the former might look like using Bootstrap 4 and as few custom styles as possible.

```css
.myPill a {
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

.myPill img {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myPill d-flex-inline text-center">
  <a href="#null" class="d-inline-block rounded-pill px-3 py-2">
    <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gj07ovBA5rvPW7w90kJll5j3_oqFbc1hpADM4F91w" />
    <span class="ml-2">User</span>
  </a>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

In the above code we're using `d-flex-inline` (a utility component for Bootstrap 4.x) to apply `display: inline-flex` to the `<div>` element which lets us break out of the block-level nature of `<div>`.

We apply `d-inline-block` to your hyperlink so that the background will wrap around the element properly, and allow for proper centering and spacing.  Additional utility classes like `px-3` and `py-2` are used to provide additional padding.

The only custom CSS you would need in this example is what is necessary to apply your own custom background color and to ensure that the `img` is properly sized.  In the above example I used a single class that then targets sibling HTML elements but you may prefer to apply additional classes to those elements rather than targeting them directly.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.myImg {
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;
}

.card .card-body .userbg {
  background-color: #d3d3d;
  width: 20%!important;
  height: 20% !important;
  padding:1%; 
  box-sizing:border-box; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not duplicate the same answer. If you have additional information, you can add it to the answer you already have. Also, FYI it is bad practice to use `!important` and it generally should not be recommended as a "hack" to overcome an issue. It is always better to fix the actual problem as using `!important` can cause even more problems down the line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the output you need is the card you have shown above. Try this.

```css
.myImg {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  border-radius:30px;
  float:middle;
  margin-left:100px;
}

.userbg {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border-radius:20px;
}

.card-title{
text-align:center; 
font-size:20px;
font-family:Helvetica;
margin-bottom:-5px;
}

.card{
width:100px;
height:200px;
margin:5px;
padding:10px;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.card-text, #text{
text-align:center; 
font-size:15px;
font-family:Helvetica;

}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">

     <h5 class="card-title" >Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>

     <div class="text-center userbg rounded-pill" style="text-align:center">
      <a href=""><img class="img-fluid rounded-circle myImg" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gj07ovBA5rvPW7w90kJll5j3_oqFbc1hpADM4F91w"> 
     <span id="text" style="float:right; margin:15px 10px 10px 0px; margin-right:90px; color:#3895D3" >User</span>
       </a>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution.

The code is found here:
[w3schools how to create contact chips](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_contact_chips.asp)